# Matching cells with conditional formatting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two reports in Excel that contain approximately the same information but are in a jumbled order and sorting doesn't help.

I need to match the batch numbers on each report and *if* the batch number matches, *then* I need to see if the dollar amount for that specific batch matches on both reports. 
For example: I want to match the batch number in column J to the batch number in Column L. IF those match, then I want to match the Column K amount tied to the batch number in Column J to the amount in Column M tied to the batch number in Column L.

I have tried conditional formatting to match the batch numbers then sort the sheets by batch number and try to match the amounts that way but that leads me to matching the amounts manually. I basically want to find a formula that will spit out a YES or NO if the batch amount doesn't match on both spreadsheets. Below is what I have been able to do manually by matching the batch number and sorting. Now I need help getting the batch amounts to match.

Any suggestions for me? Thank you!

[image: Actual Data Sample]

EDIT: updated sample after using answer:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiHpm.png)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1448365/edit) to provide us with sample data, expected outcome and what you have tried so far

Comment: I edited the question to explain what I tried so far.

Comment: Please also include sample data and expected outcome. Right now your question is at risk of being closed for being too broad. [This](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) may help you improve it

Comment: I have added the actual data sample. Does that help? I have tried doing a custom conditional formatting but it isn't working and I feel like I need more of an IF/THEN statement.

Comment: Try googling "excel match multiple criteria" and you'll get pages of explanation and examples.  If that isn't what you're looking for or doesn't solve the problem, please add clarification to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in N2 and drag downwards :

```
=IF(J2="","",IFERROR(IF(MATCH(1,INDEX((J2=L:L)*(K2=M:M),0,1),0)>0,"OK",""),"NoMatch"))
```

ref [link](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria).

hope it helps. ( :